# Pass input value whcih is outside of the form on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown which lists a list of users. So when I select a user from the list a radio button appears with the options Modify user details,Change user Permissions, Warn User

Upon selecting the option from the radio option, I load a php form

```
<select id="user_id" name="user_id" class="form-control">
<option value="1">John</option>
<option value="2">Jake</option>
</select>


<input name="change" value="1" type="radio">
<input name="change" value="2" type="radio">
<input name="change" value="3" type="radio">
```

Form (Change the username)

```
<form id="change_name" >
<input name ="username" />
<input value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Form (Change the permission)

```
<form id="change_permission" >
<input name ="permission_id" />
<input value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

each of these forms have a separate submit handler (below is just one example coz all the forms have a similar one)

```
$("#change_name").validate({
       debug: true,
       rules: {
            username: {
                required: true
            },

       },
       messages:{
           //messages     
       },
       submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({  
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'http://localhost/test/changename.php',
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              success(function(data) {
                if (data){
                    alert("success");
                    $(this)[0].reset();
                }
              })
            });
            return false;
       }
  });
```

The problem that im having is i cant find a way to pass the `user_id` value when the form is being submitted because that input field is outside the form.

Can someone please tell me what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Something like `$('#form1, #form2').serialize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize basically takes key/value pairs and concatenate them in a format: `key=value&key1=value1` if you want to add something extra you can do normal string concatenation.

```
$(this).serialize() + "&" + "user_id=" + $('#user_id').val()
```

You might need to add your logic for validation of user_id if any.

You can even serialise multiple forms together like `$('#form1, #form2').serialize()`